# How to move a form when user drags through panel, label, etc?

Tags: winforms, visual-c++, move

I wish to move whole form when user drags through the panel or label or any item i want.
How can i do this in VisualC++ ?
I know to do so in VB, but i am working in VisualC++.
Any help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if there are other alternatives to this, but you could create your own handler for WM_MOUSEDOWN (don't remember it exactly). Then all you do is work out the differences between the clicked position and the controller.

Also, in order for it to move you need to handle WM_MOUSEMOVE or something, to move the form with the pointer.

You could do this by simply having a boolean tell mousemove if it should react on mouse movements or not.

Answer (score 0):

1. Select MainForm
2. From **Properties Window** Select **Events** and Add **MouseMove** Event
3. The Code:

   ```
   public int X_cood;
   bool Mouse_Cord_Stored = false;
   int MainForm_Mouse_X_Coordinates;
   int MainForm_Mouse_Y_Coordinates;
   Point p = new Point(ActiveForm.Location.X, ActiveForm.Location.Y);

   private void MainForm_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
   {
       switch (e.Button)
       {
           case (MouseButtons.Left)://To Let user move the Form1 when Left mouse button is pressed
               {
                   switch (Mouse_Cord_Stored)
                   {
                       case false:
                           {
                               //If Mouse Coordinates are not stored, then store them.
                               MainForm_Mouse_X_Coordinates = e.X;
                               MainForm_Mouse_Y_Coordinates= e.Y;
                               Mouse_Cord_Stored = true;
                               break;
                           }
                       case true:
                           {
                               //Move the Form using ActiveForm.Location if mouse coordinates are stored
                               Form1.ActiveForm.Location = new Point(Form1.ActiveForm.Location.X + e.X - MainForm_Mouse_X_Coordinates
                                                                           , Form1.ActiveForm.Location.Y + e.Y - MainForm_Mouse_Y_Coordinates);
                               break;
                           }
                   }
                   break;
               }

           default:
               {
                   switch (Mouse_Cord_Stored)
                   {
                       case true:
                           {
                               Mouse_Cord_Stored = false;
                               break;
                           }
                   }
                   break;
               }
       }
   ```